# Making a c++ dictionary by using linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

Hope all of you doing great

I just got a project of creating a dictionary by using singularLinkedLists in such a way that each node must hold the data in a sorted order **(for e.g first node holds the 'A' char words then in that specific node the words will be in sorted form)..**

I'm not coming up with any kind of solution, A little help is appreciated

Comment: How would you do this with plain arrays? If you can figure that out, then translating to linked list will require just little more effort.

Comment: 1) create a linked list datastructure (or reuse an existing one).  2) when adding a word, insert it in between the words based on alphabetical order. 3) repeat two.

Comment: For that I have to use 2D-Arrays right...

Comment: No. A linked-list has nothing to do with an array. A linked list is created by joining structures that contain your data and a pointer to the next structure in the list (and a previous stuct pointer if the list is doubly-linked). There are hundreds, if not thousands, of examples of a linked list on this site.

Comment: so @PepijnKramer I have to do sorted insertion got it

Comment: Yup that's just basically it

Answer (score 2):

An interesting problem. Let me see, how I can help you.

At first. Let us check and analyze your requirements.

- You need a sorted singly linked list
- Additionally, a dictionary, also implemented as sorted linked list is needed
- Each node must hold the data (the capital letter of words) as a key
- The associated value for the key is again a list of words, starting with the key

So, obviously we need two data structures

1. A singly linked list to hold strings
2. A dictionary, so an associative container, that can hold a key and an associated value. Here, the list from number 1

For the design, we will first think on how a singly linked sorted list can be created. A singly linked list in general, consists of nodes, containing 2 major items

1. The data (can be anything, including a struct, an array, or just a primitive data type)
2. A “next” pointer pointing to the next node in the singly linked list

Let us show some simple picture for a demo list with integer data.

```
Head Pointer:                                            pointer to Node 1  

Node 1       data: 10       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 2
Node 2       data: 11       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 3
Node 3       data: 12       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 4
Node 4       data: 13       next-pointer:        nullptr   (empty, point to nothing)
```

As you can see. The next-pointer of a node, points to the next node in the list, hence the term “Linked List”. And you can always find any node, by starting at the head pointer and then follow all next-pointers.

A simple structure for a node could look for example like:

```
// A sorted singly linked list forstd::string + special iterator
class SortedSingleLinkedList {

    // Structure of one node
    struct Node {
        // The data in the dictionay. A std::string
        std::string value{};

        // Pointer to next node
        Node* next{ nullptr };
    };

    // Start of list
    Node* head{ nullptr };
```

For normal, non-sorted lists, adding an element to the list is simple. We create a new node with the net data. Then, we check, if the list is empty. Meaning, is the head-pointer == nullptr. In this case, we assign the new node to the head node pointer.

If we have already elements in the linked list, then we just follow all next-pointers until we find a nullptr and just hang in the new node instead of the last nullptr. That is rather simple.

If we want to have a sorted list, then we will insert the new node at the correct place.

We have to differentiate 3 cases:

1. The list is empty. Then the new node will become the head node
2. The new nodes data is smaller than the head nodes data. Then we make the new node to the head node and assign the previous head node to the new nodes head pointer. Also simple.
3. Last but not least, we will iterate through the list via the next-pointers and check, if the data is smaller than the next data. In that case, we need to insert the element.

Example: We want to insert a new-node with data 15 in the below list

```
Head Pointer:                                            pointer to Node 1  

Node 1       data: 10       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 2
Node 2       data: 11       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 3
Node 3       data: 21       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 4
Node 4       data: 22       next-pointer:        nullptr   (empty, point to nothing)
```

Then we iterate through the list by using the next-pointer and next-data. If we are at Node 3 and check the next-node (Node 3), then we will find out that the data of the new-node (15) is smaller than the data of the next-node (Note 3, data 21).

We need to insert the new-node behind Node 2 and before Node 3. To achieve that, we assign to the new-nodes next-pointer the address of the old address from Node 2’s next pointer (which was pointing to Node 3 before: `new-node->next-pointer = current-node->next pointer`

After this we assign to the current-node(Node 2)‘s next-pointer the address of the new-node. `Node 2->next-pointer = new-node`. And then the old address from

In a small

```
Head Pointer:                                    pointer to Node 1  

Node-new     data: 15     next-pointer:          nullptr   (empty, point to nothing)


Node 1       data: 10       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 2
Node 2       data: 11       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 3
Node 3       data: 21       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 4
Node 4       data: 22       next-pointer:        nullptr   (empty, point to nothing)


// Step 1
Node-new     data: 15     next-pointer:          pointer to Node 3

// Step 2 
Node 2       data: 11       next-pointer:        pointer to Node-New

// which will result in:

Node 1       data: 10       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 2
Node 2       data: 11       next-pointer:        pointer to Node-new
Node-new     data: 15       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 3
Node 3       data: 21       next-pointer:        pointer to Node 4
Node 4       data: 22       next-pointer:        nullptr   (empty, point to nothing)
```

This should be understandable now. And this can be easily implemented as given in the design above. Example code:

```
// Main function. Insert a new value into the list, but sorted. So, insertion sort
    Node* insertSorted(const std::string& value) {

        // Create a new node
        Node* newNode = new Node({ value });

        // If the list is empty
        if (head == nullptr) {

            // Then now the start of the list will be the new node
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {

            // There was already data here. Initialize an iterator pointer
            Node* current = head;

            // If the new element is smaller than the head element
            if ( newNode->value < head->value) {
                
                // Then we nmake the new element the head element
                newNode->next = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
            else {

                // Iterate over elements and check, if the new element is samller then the next element
                while ((current->next != nullptr) and (current->next->value < newNode->value))
                    current = current->next;

                // So, now we found the element, after which we need to insert the new element
                newNode->next = current->next;
                current->next = newNode;
            }
        }
        return newNode;
    }
```

So, you could now add a lot of additional functions that are all easy. Like `isEmpty()` or `size()` or `find`. Or, whatever you may need.

I added, for easier output and iteration a complete iterator functionality for this class in order to be able to easily iterate over all elements, for example in loops.

Next, the dictionary.

We will implement the dictionary basically in the same way as described above. So, also as a singly sorted list. We can reuse all the mechanisms from above and it will work identically.

The main difference is that the data in the node now consists of 2 items:

1. The key. In our case a character
2. The value, in our case the above defined singly linked sorted list for strings

We will the letter assign to a key (we will use an uppercase letter for the key), a list with words (strings).

In order to achieve that we create a special index operator, similar to that of the `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` from C++.

This will do the following. It will take the index value given in the brackets `[]` and search, if this is existing in the list. If it is not existing, then a new entry with the key (the index given in the bracket `[]`) is created. And a reference to the value, here a newly created empty sorted linked list for strings, is returned.

If the key value could be found in the list, then also a reference, this time to the existing value, is returned.

So, whatever we do, after the usage of the index operator, we will always have a reference to the associated singly linked sorted list. And, we can then add a new word (string) to this list. This means: `dictionary[key]`will always return a reference to a `SortedSingleLinkedList` and for that we can call the above  `insertSorted(word);`-function.

The whole thing will then look like this:

```
dictionary[key].insertSorted(word);
```

This will create a new key, or find an existing key and then return the linked list for words, in which we insert a new word.

Cool.

And because we also add an iterator to the dictionary class, we can easily iterate over that in a range based for loop.

Please note: The experienced user will immediately notice the nearly 100% similarity of both classes. In reality such classes would be implemented by using template functionality and reduce the code size drastically with it.

Anyway. Let’s go for the moment with a full hand written example code. Please see below one of many many possible solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <cctype>

// A sorted singly linked list forstd::string + special iterator
class SortedSingleLinkedList {

    // Structure of one node
    struct Node {
        // The data in the dictionay. A std::string
        std::string value{};

        // Pointer to next node
        Node* next{ nullptr };
    };

    // Start of list
    Node* head{ nullptr };

public: 

    // Destructor will delete all dynamic data, so all nodes
    ~SortedSingleLinkedList() {

        // Start with the head
        Node* runningNodePtr = head;

        // As long as there are nodes
        while (runningNodePtr != nullptr) {

            // Get next element pointer
            Node* temp = runningNodePtr->next;

            // Delete the current element
            delete runningNodePtr;

            // And continue with next element
            runningNodePtr = temp;
        }
    };

    // Main function. Insert a new value into the list, but sorted. So, insertion sort
    Node* insertSorted(const std::string& value) {

        // Create a new node
        Node* newNode = new Node({ value });

        // If the list is empty
        if (head == nullptr) {

            // Then now the start of the list will be the new node
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {

            // There was already data here. Initialize an iterator pointer
            Node* current = head;

            // If the new element is smaller than the head element
            if ( newNode->value < head->value) {
                
                // Then we nmake the new element the head element
                newNode->next = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
            else {

                // Iterate over elements and check, if the new element is samller then the next element
                while ((current->next != nullptr) and (current->next->value < newNode->value))
                    current = current->next;

                // So, now we found the element, after which we need to insert the new element
                newNode->next = current->next;
                current->next = newNode;
            }
        }
        return newNode;
    }


    // Add iterator properties to class ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Special dereferencing iterator tha will return the data, so the string value, not the node
    // Local class for iterator
    class iterator {
        Node* iter{};                             // This will be the iterator 
    public:                                    // Define alias names necessary for the iterator functionality
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = Node*;
        using pointer = Node**;
        using reference = Node*&;

        explicit iterator(Node* i) : iter(i) {};  // Default constructor for the iterator
        std::string operator *() const { return (iter == nullptr) ?std::string() : iter->value; } // Dereferencing
        iterator& operator ++() { if (iter!=nullptr) iter = iter->next; return *this; } // Pre-Increment
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) { return iter != other.iter; }  // Comparison
    };

    // Begin and end function to initiliaze an iterator
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(nullptr); }
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// A Dictionary, with a key and a value
// Her the valueis again a sorted list with strings
class Dictionary {

    // Structur of one node. Contains the key (a character) and the value (a sortedlist with strings)
    struct Node {

        // The data in the dictionay. The y key
        char key{};

        // A sorted list with strings
        SortedSingleLinkedList value{};

        // Pointer to next node
        Node* next{ nullptr };
    };

    // The start of pur linked list
    Node* head{ nullptr };

public:

    // Destructor will releas previously allocated memory for Nodes
    ~Dictionary() {

        // Start with the head
        Node* runningNodePtr = head;

        // Iterate over all elements in the List
        while (runningNodePtr != nullptr) {

            // Get next element
            Node* temp = runningNodePtr->next;

            // Delete current element
            delete runningNodePtr;

            // And continue with next element
            runningNodePtr = temp;
        }
    };

    // A very special indexoperator that is quite common in associative containers
    // It will frost check, if the element given as index is in the list
    // If not then a new element for this key will be generated
    // In any case, a reference to either the found or the new element will be returned

    SortedSingleLinkedList& operator [](const char& key) {
        Node* current = head;
        while ((current != nullptr) and not (current->key == key)) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        if (current == nullptr)
            return insertSorted(key, {})->value;
        else
            return current->value;
    }

    // Insert a value sorted by the key into the list
    Node* insertSorted(const char& key, const SortedSingleLinkedList& value) {

        // Create a new node
        Node* newNode = new Node({ key, value });

        // If the list was empty, then we simply assign the new node to the head
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            // Iteration variable will start at the head
            Node* current = head;

            // Special handling of first element. Check, if we need to insert something before the head
            if (newNode->key < head->key) {
                newNode->next = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
            else {
                // Iterate over all elements and check, if our key value is smaller the next key value in the list
                while ((current->next != nullptr) and (current->next->key < newNode->key))
                    current = current->next;

                // Insert element in list
                newNode->next = current->next;
                current->next = newNode;
            }
        }
        return newNode;
    }


    // Add iterator properties to class ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // The dereferencing operator will not return a Node* but a reference to a pair, consisting of the 
    // key and the value, so, the sorted linked list of strings
    // Local class for iterator
    class iterator {
        Node* iter{};                          // This will be the iterator 
    public:                                    // Define alias names necessary for the iterator functionality
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = Node*;
        using pointer = Node**;
        using reference = Node*&;

        explicit iterator(Node* i) : iter(i) {};  // Default constructor for the iterator
        std::pair<char&, SortedSingleLinkedList&> operator *() const { return { iter->key, iter->value }; } // Dereferencing
        iterator& operator ++() { if (iter != nullptr) iter = iter->next; return *this; } // Pre-Increment
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) { return iter != other.iter; }  // Comparison
    };

    // Begin and end function to initiliaze an iterator
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(nullptr); }
};


// Some test string
std::istringstream test{ R"(Wafer chupa chups pudding jelly chocolate cupcake chocolate cake. Candy canes brownie gummies cookie toffee. Sesame snaps 
liquorice candy tootsie roll jelly beans. Icing gingerbread apple pie fruitcake jelly-o chocolate cake chocolate chupa chups. Pie gummi bears cookie 
fruitcake pastry pudding jelly-o. Tootsie roll ice cream macaroon powder sugar plum powder liquorice. Danish ice cream donut soufflé bonbon halvah 
jujubes gummi bears. Brownie tiramisu gingerbread candy canes dessert. Cookie cheesecake cake pastry wafer pie cookie cake. Lollipop chocolate bar 
bonbon marzipan pie caramels marzipan. Jelly-o jujubes dessert candy canes tootsie roll croissant. Marzipan pastry pudding lemon drops jelly beans 
gingerbread apple pie. Danish muffin gummies candy brownie muffin sweet roll jelly beans. Donut bonbon dessert halvah gummies lemon drops)" };

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Test function / driver code
int main() {

    // A dictionary for a key (The capitalize letter of the word and a list of words starting with a letter
    Dictionary dictionary;

    // Extract all words from the string
    std::string word{};
    while (test >> word) {

        // Wewill use the uppercase first letter of the word as key
        char key = char(std::toupper(word[0]));

        // FInd or add a key and then insert the word into its value, the sorted list of strings
        dictionary[key].insertSorted(word);
    }
    // Debug output. Show the complete dictionary. Loops are possible because we created iterators
    for (const auto& [key, stringList] : dictionary) {

        std::cout << "\n\n" << key << ":\n";        // Show the key
        for (const std::string s : stringList)
            std::cout << s << ' ';                  // And show the associated words
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the input shown in the source code, we will get the following output:

```
A:
apple apple


B:
Brownie bar beans beans. beans. bears bears. bonbon bonbon bonbon brownie brownie


C:
Candy Cookie cake cake cake. cake. candy candy candy candy canes canes canes caramels cheesecake chocolate chocolate chocolate chocolate chocolate chupa chupa chups chups. cookie cookie cookie cream cream croissant. cupcake


D:
Danish Danish Donut dessert dessert dessert. donut drops drops


F:
fruitcake fruitcake


G:
gingerbread gingerbread gingerbread gummi gummi gummies gummies gummies


H:
halvah halvah


I:
Icing ice ice


J:
Jelly-o jelly jelly jelly jelly jelly-o jelly-o. jujubes jujubes


L:
Lollipop lemon lemon liquorice liquorice.


M:
Marzipan macaroon marzipan marzipan. muffin muffin


P:
Pie pastry pastry pastry pie pie pie pie. plum powder powder pudding pudding pudding


R:
roll roll roll roll


S:
Sesame snaps soufflé sugar sweet


T:
Tootsie tiramisu toffee. tootsie tootsie


W:
Wafer wafer
```

I hope that I could give an understandable example